# Optimising SQL Query with repeated case statements

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-function

I have the following setup:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
perf_id INT,
build_id INT,
series_id INT,
client_id INT,
measurement INT
);

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 10);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (2, 1, 2, 1, 15);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (3, 2, 1, 1, 10);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (4, 2, 2, 1, 15);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (5, 2, 2, 1, 20);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (6, 3, 1, 1, 10);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (7, 3, 2, 1, 20);
```

I then Query this with the following:

```
SELECT
build_id,
CONCAT(
MIN(CASE WHEN series_id IN (1) THEN measurement ELSE NULL END),
';',
AVG(CASE WHEN series_id IN (1) THEN measurement ELSE NULL END),
';',
MAX(CASE WHEN series_id IN (1) THEN measurement ELSE NULL END)
),
CONCAT(
MIN(CASE WHEN series_id IN (2) THEN measurement ELSE NULL END),
';',
AVG(CASE WHEN series_id IN (2) THEN measurement ELSE NULL END),
';',
MAX(CASE WHEN series_id IN (2) THEN measurement ELSE NULL END)
)
FROM table_name GROUP BY build_id;
```

You can find a sqlFiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efef8/17

I would like to optimise my query, mostly to reduce the repeated code. I will be calling this from PHP, and binding in values for the IN operator.

I figured a function could replace the bulk of repeated code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION data(s INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
RETURN CONCAT(
MIN(CASE WHEN series_id IN (s) THEN measurement ELSE NULL END),
';',
AVG(CASE WHEN series_id IN (s) THEN measurement ELSE NULL END),
';',
MAX(CASE WHEN series_id IN (s) THEN measurement ELSE NULL END)
)
```

But this complains of inappropriate use of aggregate function. I'm also not sure how I'd pass in an array for the IN operator.

NB:

1. The concat operator doesn't seem to work on SQLFiddle, but does on my machine. I don't know if I've messed up some syntax?
2. The number of columns will be variable.
3. I will also be controlling a WHERE statement before the GROUP BY, however I have this working, I just don't wish to repeat my concat a million times.

Comment: SQL doesn't have arrays. You can create a temporary table, and then use `WHEN series_id IN (SELECT id FROM temptable)`

Comment: But you can't use aggregate functions like `MIN` and `AVG` in the function, because they operate on the result set of a query, not on individual values.

Comment: I suppose the term array came from that being the PHP variable I shall be binding to it. I take it that I cannot pass a variable length "array" like "(1)" or "(1,2,3,4,5)" into a function? Can I pass a table into a function? And create this temporary table, then pass in?

Comment: No, you can't put a string there, it won't automatically split it up. Variable substitution doesn't work by interpolating text and reparsing the query, it just treats it as a single value to compare with the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a select from in your function. Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

create FUNCTION data(s INT, id int)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
    DECLARE res VARCHAR(50);
    SET res = (SELECT CONCAT(
MIN(CASE WHEN series_id IN (s) THEN measurement ELSE NULL END),
';',
AVG(CASE WHEN series_id IN (s) THEN measurement ELSE NULL END),
';',
MAX(CASE WHEN series_id IN (s) THEN measurement ELSE NULL END)
)
from table_name
where build_id = id);
    RETURN res;
END$$


select
t.build_id
, data(1, t.build_id)
, data(2, t.build_id)
from table_name t
group by t.build_id
```

Comment: This looks perfect! I guess the only downside is that any filters I'd want to put on the main query would also be passed down to the function. But that doesn't seem like too much of an issue. (i.e. if I wanted to limit all my results by client id I'd have to add that limit on the function and pass it in. In fact I think the WHERE client_id=X is only needed in the inner query now?)

Comment: @Deoxyribonucleic If I understand you correctly then if you change the function to `FUNCTION data(s INT, id int, clientid int)` and change the WHERE inside the function to add `client_id = clientid` then outer query will only need to change to `, data(2, t.build_id, t.client_id)
from table_name t
group by t.build_id`

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was thinking. So it still isn't repeated as it's only inside the function that I must define my constraints

Comment: Accepted as this works perfectly. However it ended up that the performance was less than stellar. I ended up creating the repeated code  when generating the query, and then binding the values multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about rows where the values are `0`:

```
SELECT build_id,
       CONCAT_WS(';', MIN(measurement), AVG(measurement), MAX(measurement)),
FROM table_name
WHERE series_id = 2
GROUP BY build_id;
```

To get the other rows:

```
SELECT build_id,
       CONCAT_WS(';', MIN(measurement), AVG(measurement), MAX(measurement)),
FROM table_name
WHERE series_id = 2
GROUP BY build_id
UNION ALL
SELECT build_id, ''
FROM table_name
GROUP BY build_id
HAVING MAX(series_id = 2) = 0;
```

Comment: CONCAT_WS looks perfect! But I'm not sure I understand how the second half of your code works? I shall experiment with it and see if that makes it clearer.

Comment: The first query gets the build_id that have a `series_id = 2`.  The second query has a second subquery that gets the rest of the rows (note:  I fixed the logic in the `having` so it is correct).